# rosjava build error in kinetic: Could not find org.ros.rosjava_messages:tf:1.11.9

Tags: rosjava, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to update from ROS Indigo (and Ubuntu 14) to ROS Kinetic (and Ubuntu 16)
While my code builds under Indigo, when I try to do a catkin_make under Kinetic, I always get the same build failure when trying to generate rosjava bindings for my .msg and .srv files.
The rest of the project builds fine - compiling C++ code, generating Python bindings for the .msg & .srv files, etc.

The build failure:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtime'.

> Could not find org.ros.rosjava_messages:tf:1.11.9.
> Searched in the following locations:
> file:/home/grabit/svn/trunk/ros_linux/catkin_ws/devel/share/maven/org/ros/rosjava_messages/tf/1.11.9/tf-1.11.9.pom
> file:/home/grabit/svn/trunk/ros_linux/catkin_ws/devel/share/maven/org/ros/rosjava_messages/tf/1.11.9/tf-1.11.9.jar
> file:/opt/ros/kinetic/share/maven/org/ros/rosjava_messages/tf/1.11.9/tf-1.11.9.pom
> file:/opt/ros/kinetic/share/maven/org/ros/rosjava_messages/tf/1.11.9/tf-1.11.9.jar
> https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo/raw/master/org/ros/rosjava_messages/tf/1.11.9/tf-1.11.9.pom
> https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo/raw/master/org/ros/rosjava_messages/tf/1.11.9/tf-1.11.9.jar
> file:/home/grabit/.m2/repository/org/ros/rosjava_messages/tf/1.11.9/tf-1.11.9.pom
> file:/home/grabit/.m2/repository/org/ros/rosjava_messages/tf/1.11.9/tf-1.11.9.jar
> http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/ros/rosjava_messages/tf/1.11.9/tf-1.11.9.pom
> http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/ros/rosjava_messages/tf/1.11.9/tf-1.11.9.jar
> http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/org/ros/rosjava_messages/tf/1.11.9/tf-1.11.9.pom
> http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/org/ros/rosjava_messages/tf/1.11.9/tf-1.11.9.jar
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ros/rosjava_messages/tf/1.11.9/tf-1.11.9.pom
> [ 65%] Generating EusLisp code from stackit_srvs/ConveyorPosition.srv
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ros/rosjava_messages/tf/1.11.9/tf-1.11.9.jar
> Required by:
> org.ros.rosjava_messages:stackit_srvs:0.0.0
> Could not find org.ros.rosjava_messages:stackit_msgs:0.0.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> file:/home/grabit/svn/trunk/ros_linux/catkin_ws/devel/share/maven/org/ros/rosjava_messages/stackit_msgs/0.0.0/stackit_msgs-0.0.0.pom
> file:/home/grabit/svn/trunk/ros_linux/catkin_ws/devel/share/maven/org/ros/rosjava_messages/stackit_msgs/0.0.0/stackit_msgs-0.0.0.jar
> file:/opt/ros/kinetic/share/maven/org/ros/rosjava_messages/stackit_msgs/0.0.0/stackit_msgs-0.0.0.pom
> file:/opt/ros/kinetic/share/maven/org/ros/rosjava_messages/stackit_msgs/0.0.0/stackit_msgs-0.0.0.jar
> https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo/raw/master/org/ros/rosjava_messages/stackit_msgs/0.0.0/stackit_msgs-0.0.0.pom
> https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo/raw/master/org/ros/rosjava_messages/stackit_msgs/0.0.0/stackit_msgs-0.0.0.jar
> file:/home/grabit/.m2/repository/org/ros/rosjava_messages/stackit_msgs/0.0.0/stackit_msgs-0.0.0.pom
> file:/home/grabit/.m2/repository/org/ros/rosjava_messages/stackit_msgs/0.0.0/stackit_msgs-0.0.0.jar
> http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/ros/rosjava_messages/stackit_msgs/0.0.0/stackit_msgs-0.0.0.pom
> http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/ros/rosjava_messages/stackit_msgs/0.0.0/stackit_msgs-0.0.0.jar
> http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/org/ros/rosjava_messages/stackit_msgs/0.0.0/stackit_msgs-0.0.0.pom
> http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/org/ros/rosjava_messages/stackit_msgs/0.0.0/stackit_msgs-0.0.0.jar
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ros/rosjava_messages/stackit_msgs/0.0.0/stackit_msgs-0.0.0.pom
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ros/rosjava_messages/stackit_msgs/0.0.0/stackit_msgs-0.0.0.jar
> Required by:
> org.ros.rosjava_messages:stackit_srvs:0.0.0

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276858/rosjava-build-error-in-kinetic:-could-not-find-org.ros.rosjava_messages:tf:1.11.9/) by [rbiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/32798/rbiro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-11-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2017-11-29**:
It seems that the artifact for that version is missing in rosjava_mvn_repo:https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo/tree/master/org/ros/rosjava_messages/tf.

I will add it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@rbiro this is a known issue in `genjava`.

When you create a new custom service/ message, `genjava` will add a dependency to the messages you have installed in your system (in this case, for `tf`, the message version is 1.11.9).

The problem is that the latest version of the messages is not always available in `rosjava_mvn_repo`. I will add it when I can (the problem is that I will also need to update the version of it's dependencies, so it might take a while).

In the meantime, maybe you can try going to /home/grabit/svn/trunk/ros_linux/catkin_ws/devel/share/maven/org/ros/rosjava_messages/stackit_msgs/0.0.0/stackit_msgs-0.0.0.pom , and edit the dependency to `tf:1.11.8` manually. See https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo/issues/46 for reference.

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2017-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/45221/rosmax/) on 2020-09-18**:
Hi @jubeira,
I have the same problem now with:

```
org.ros.rosjava_messages:roscpp:1.12.16

org.ros.rosjava_messages:topic_tools:1.12.16

org.ros.rosjava_messages:actionlib:1.11.16
```

They don't seem to be available in the `rosjava_mvn_repo`. Unfortunately, I don't have any `devel/share/maven` directory in my workspace so I cannot modify the dependencies on my own. Do you have any ideas? Regards